# JCheckBox and JCheckBoxMenuItem java

Tags: java, swing

I was looking at these two examples and I was curious what the difference is between JCheckBox and JCheckBoxMenuItem.

http://pastebin.com/hLe3mEd8

These pictures make it look they are the same except JCheckBox is not in a menu but it is easy to add to a menu with the menu_name.add(menu_item) command. Is that correct?

http://pastebin.com/hLe3mEd8

Comment: One is for adding into menus and one is not?  Generally speaking, you would never add a `JCheckBoxMenuItem` to anything other then a menu...

Comment: [crossposted](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/488358/jcheckbox-vs-jcheckboxmenuitem)